# How to access google classroom api from my android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin, google-classroom

I'm trying to make an android app that fetches information from a user's google classroom account (classes, homework, ...) after the user signs in.

Thanks to the tutorial at : [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), the user can sign in but now I'm left wondering how to get a google classroom service from his logged in account.

I've already requested the necessary scopes `(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSES)`, here is the code that I've been working with :

```java
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //google sign in stuff
       GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
               .requestEmail()
               .requestScopes(new Scope(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSES))
               .build();

       mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

       //will return GoogleSignInAccount if user already signed in before
       GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

   }


   public void loadClassroomAndroid(View v){
       Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
       startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
           // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
           // a listener.
           Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
           GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(Exception.class);

           //How can I get a Classroom object from this account ?
           //Or at least get a user's classroom info ?
       }
   }
```

Comment: have you tried checking this https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/java

Comment: Yes I have. Sadly, the authorization flow used doesn't work in an android environment.